# Can't use queue created by newRequestQueue from Volley library

Tags: java, android, http, kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to create my first app in Kotlin. I'm using the Volley library by

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

I'm using this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple), so my code is the same:

```
package com.example.raspberrycontrol

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textfield)

val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "http://www.google.com"

val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

queue.add(stringRequest)

fun httpsRequest(view: View){
}
```

My problem is that I get an error on

```
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

When I mouseover it, it says that it's "Expecting member declaration", as if I didn't do it few lines before with this:

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
```

What am I doing wrong here or missing?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have added needs to be inside the `onCreate()`{ scope }.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textfield)

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "http://www.google.com"

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url,
    Response.Listener<String> { response ->
        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
        textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
    },
    Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

    queue.add(stringRequest)

}
```

Comment: If the queue is defined in `onCreate`, how to use it in another function of the same class as `Volley.newRequestQueue` should be only inited once?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
private void getAuthTocken() {


         RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://www.google.com", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        oAuth_model = gson.fromJson(response, oAuth_Model.class);
                        if (oAuth_model != null){
                           Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(oAuth_model));
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("oAuth","Authorize failed");
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("string","string");   
                        return params;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                queue.add(sr);

            }


    Kotlin:

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textfield)

            val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            val url = "http://www.google.com"

            val stringReq[![enter image description here][2]][2]uest = StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url,
                Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    textView.text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { textView.text = "That didn't work!" })

            queue.add(stringRequest)
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering the question; it will be even more helpful if you describe how your answer solves the issue.  Please [edit] it and add a short description.  Thanks!

Comment: My answer was for JAVA, And Kotlin Version will be updated asap